# iMac Pixelated Screen

Tags: imac

I just recently acquired an iMac. I'm not sure what model it is or anything but the attached pictures show it.

When it boots up there's a pixelated screen and it won't boot into the OS, and when I try to boot from a CD it says that the computer needs to restart.

[image: screen]
[image: msg]

Comment: Hmm. Might be an issue with the video card. You might have to go to the Apple Store and ask the staff there to replace it. If you want to replace it, just replace the whole motherboard (Apple would charge an expensive amount of $s!).

Comment: Reset PRAM then internet recovery tool

Answer (score 1):

First, try to boot it off a different drive. It is possible (unlikely) that this is severe data corruption on the drive. You can use another Mac in target disk mode, or you can use internet recovery, or you can use a bootable external drive if you have one.

If you boot another drive and still have the graphic distortions then it is certainly a logic board issue. If it functions normally (this is not likely) then you just need a new hard drive, or maybe just a wipe and reinstall. It's unlikely but worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

The model & serial numbers are on the underside of the foot. That doesn't have any bearing on the issues you're seeing- an inability to boot from its internal drive as well as a corrupted video signal showing a kernel panic screen- which is probably the result of a hardware failure in the display cable or connector or an issue with the system board video circuitry.

Another possibility is that the previous owner got a little too adventurous & mishandled disconnecting or reconnecting the front panel's display connector. Ifixit.com has instructions on how to open your model iMac so you can check the connectors for damage.

You may not have much recourse if you were not informed that the iMac was in this condition before you purchased it other than to have it repaired at your nearest Apple repair shop or Apple Store.

Comment: Well, it was free so if it's toast I assume it's probably out of warranty + fine to open up. How much would a repair job go for, though, if I took it to apple?

Comment: Also, I popped a windows disk in and it seemed to stop the whole weird screen thing it had going on.

Comment: Cost of repair will depend on what's actually broken & in need of replacement. The internal drive will need attention or replacement, the system board or discrete graphics adapter (or both) may also need replacement. And last but not least the display itself may be the cause of the corrupted video issue. So there's quite a range for what it may cost to repair.

Comment: Highest cost range?

Comment: Was that a Windows install disk? Which version?

Comment: What size is the display?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46662/discussion-between-karlc-and-user2544765).